# How to create a line break in WhatsApp web?

Tags: whatsapp

The web interface does not respect the setting where 'enter' sends a message (or not); pressing 'enter' does indeed send the message.

I have composed letters in Word (including line breaks) and then pasted the text into the web interface, but this is overkill.

So how does one create a line break in WhatsApp web?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create line breaks in WhatsApp web:

[image]

Documented: https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/features/whatsapp-keyboard-shortcuts-mac-windows-app-browser-full-list-2409260

Many desktop applications and websites exhibit this behaviour as well; one of the examples is [Stack Exchange's own chat server](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes! Easy when you know how.... Thanks.

Comment: Any way to change such behavior so ENTER doesn't send the message?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel other than a keyboard mapper, I have no idea ...

Comment: @VScode_fanboy thank you for finding a source! As for the grammar, that is the British spelling and [that should not be changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/295232). (I'm not British but I like that spelling better.)

Comment: @Glorfindel blame Firefox.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy heh, mine complains about it as well. I guess I learned which spelling warnings to ignore when editing posts :)

Comment: @Glorfindel ah, that explains it well :)